# Check if specific user is online outside wp

Tags: login

I want to know if a user with a specific user id has logged in on my wordpress site.How can I achieve this accurately.

Comment: Unfortunately is_user_logged_in() does not accept any parameter

Comment: `is_user_logged_in` checks if the current user is logged in, it doesn't have the ability to check arbitrary users

Comment: You may have to be a bit clearer in your question - Do you need to check if the user has ever logged in? Or do you want to be notified every time they log in? Or, do you want to be able to find the time they have last logged in? Unfortunately, there is no way to tell if a user is 'currently logged in', as that's just not how WordPress works.

Answer (score 1):

You could always try using the `wp_login` action hook:

```
function custom_check_for_user($user_login, $user) {
    if($user->ID == 123) { // Where 123 is the particular user's ID
        // Do something here, eg. PHP mail() function
    }
}
add_action('wp_login', 'custom_check_for_user', 10, 2);
```

Further reading: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login

Comment: How do i place this code outside of wp like `Mywpsite.com/logincheck.php` . Then my other script will use the logincheck as an endpoint

Answer (score 0):

try this code, it is in user-edit.php :
`$sessions = WP_Session_Tokens::get_instance( $profileuser->ID );`